# What are the original TeX fonts installed on my computer?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to find the font I saw in some lecture notes. I think they are TeX native fonts but they might as well be fonts from Latex's packages? Please see attachment. Is there a place I can find the fonts that are native to TeX, by that I mean METAFONT?

[image]

Comment: they don't look like the (original) computer modern fonts.  key identifying points: old-style numerals (course and date), and no "fi" ligature (in "definition").

Comment: possibly `kpfonts`, which is based on palatino. There are not very many Metafont fonts other than Computer Modern.

Comment: you can use `pdffonts` or the Properties dialogue in a PDF viewer to see what fonts are used

Comment: @AndrewCashner Thanks, I opened the pdf view properties dialogue and it worked.

Comment: So was I right? (kpfonts/kepler, palatino, TeX Gyre Pagella, something in that category?)

Comment: @AndrewCashner I think the author used some URWpalladioL typeface. I am not quite sure though because the properties page give me many different fonts.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Okay, so actually there is an even easier way. I just copied a segment of the text of interest to Microsoft word, and it worked like magic.. telling me the typeface and font size.

Comment: The package used is \usepackage{mathpazo}.

Comment: @Kun, `mathpazo` loads the URW Palladio font family, based on Palatino.